# Watch points on memory address

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

With the new change from gdb to lldb , I can't find a way how to set watch points on some memory addresses .

In gdb I used this

```
watch -location *0x123456
```

Doing the same in lldb

```
w s e *0x123456
```

Isn't working for me .
So what can I use to run the same command in lldb ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Omit the "dereferencing operator" `*` when setting the watch point in lldb, just pass the address:

```
watchpoint set expression -- 0x123456
# short form:
w s e -- 0x123456
```

sets a watchpoint at the memory location `0x123456`. Optionally you can set the number of bytes to watch with `--size`. Example in short form:

```
w s e -s 2 -- 0x123456
```

You can also set a watchpoint on a variable:

```
watchpoint set variable <variable>
# short form:
w s v <variable>
```

*Example:* With the following code and a breakpoint set at the second line:

```
int x = 2;
x = 5;
```

I did this in the Xcode debugger console:

```
(lldb) p &x
(int *) $0 = 0xbfffcbd8
(lldb) w s e -- 0xbfffcbd8
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0xbfffcbd8 size = 4 state = enabled type = w
    new value: 2
(lldb) n

Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 2
new value: 5
(lldb)
```

More simply, I could have set the watchpoint with

```
(lldb) w s v x
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x7fff5fbff7dc size = 4 state = enabled type = w
    declare @ '/Users/martin/Documents/tmpprojects/watcher/watcher/main.c:16'
    watchpoint spec = 'x'
```

Comment: I get this : error expression evaluation of address to watch failed , expression evaluated

Comment: @user3001909: Strange, I had tested this. - I have added an example.

Comment: I tried your example, lldb said use of undeclared identifier 'x' . Then did w s e -- 0xOFFSET and it worked .
watchpoint created : Watchpoint 1: addr = 0xOFFSET size = 4 state ... new value :10 .
Thank you !

Comment: I've gotten this same error since I upgraded to Yosemite and had to update Xcode as well.  How can you state the range of bytes to watch from that address?

Comment: Yes the `-x` doesn't seem to be recognized in xcode 7.X

Comment: @Tylerc230: It seems to be `--size` or `-s` now. Answer updated.